# How can I write a loader for three.js?

Tags: three.js

I'd like to write an Ldraw loader for three.js; [Ldraw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LDraw) is a text-based open format for Lego models.

I'm familiar with the format (I've implemented a parser in a different language), but I have trouble understanding the three.js loader architecture.

How is a loader structured? I've tried to go through the source code of existing ones, but I need some starting guidance.

Comment: Ldraw describes a standard mesh set (pieces with color and pip configuration), rotations and positions in relation to 0,0,0. But as well Ldraw lines can describe mesh level and line info.The format, http://www.ldraw.org/article/218.html#lt1 supports a number of approaches. Supporting linetype 1 will be very different from 2-5. Have you checked if anyone has a converter into one of the loader types Three supports: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev/examples/js/loaders? I have worked with the format, (not three.js) but only in line types 0 and 1, but was able to support many models.

Comment: Thanks @Radio - I'm familiar with Ldraw, it's the three.js loader logic that I don't completely understand.

Comment: You will need to read and understand the loader classes: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev/src/loaders After reviewing those, gut/rename the SVGLoader class from the examples folder and confirm you can load a file. Then onto loadingManager. The loadingManager is most often used to load textures as in JSONLoader. You will need it for linetype 1 external files. Once you can confirm you are loading all support files, you can start work on parsing line types 2-5 in all files. Look to an example such as the OBJLoader parser as an example of how to create native Three geometry objects.